# filter all elements with defined namespaces

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, xslt-2.0, xml-namespaces

I have the following source xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:filter="filter_this" xmlns:also_filter="filter_also">
    <filter:error>This element should be filtred</filter:error>
    <ok>This is ok</ok>
    <filter:error>This element should be filtred also</filter:error>
    <ok>This is also ok</ok>
</root>
```

The task is to filter elements with namespaces, like `*:*`.
There may potentially be elements in `root` element with random namespaces, not just `filter` or `also_filter` which I gave as examples only.

So desired output should look like this:

```
This is ok
This is also ok
```

I have tried out following xslt-template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="/root/*">
            <xsl:if test="not(namespace::*)">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

which gives empty output. I need to figure out condition in `<xsl:if...></xsl:if>` statement. Please help me:)

UPD:
xslt 2.0 solutions are ok due to Saxon-HE 9.5.1.7 usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current solution fails because the namespace axis of all elements below root contains two nodes (for namespace `filter_this` and `filter_also`). So the `if` always evaluates to false.

But you can test if an element has no namespace uri:

```
<xsl:if test="not(namespace-uri())">
```

Comment: tested, this works. My misunderstanding was about selecting xpath-axe instead of comparing actual prefixes. TY.